# Does the term "flat" apply to general Banach Spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, terminology

I'm trying to refer to refer to a translate of a closed subspace of an infinite dimensional Hilbert Space, and I'm trying to come up with a more compact term to describe it. I've come across relatively recently the term "flat", which Wikipedia defines explicitly in Euclidean spaces. So, my questions are, is the term "flat" used to describe translates of subspaces of an infinite dimensional space? Can/should I use the term without clarifying what it means?

Comment: "Can/should I use the term without clarifying what it means?" You should probably never do that, especially if you are not sure about it yourself so your audience would appreciate some remarks..

Comment: Perhaps "closed affine subspace" would communicate your meaning?

Comment: @RideTheWavelet: I thought about that, but I think it's still a bit long. I think I'll follow Ravi's suggestion, and just explain what I mean. I would like to know if anyone has ever seen this term used like this before, though.

Comment: I completely agree with defining the terminology, whichever you use. You could go for "CAS," "cas," or "c.a.s." after the first usage, if you wanted, also, but I'll acknowledge that these lose some intuitive content. This still might be better than using a term that others have used to mean something else, however.

Comment: As you see from the answers, you had to define clearly (with formulas) what you had in mind.

Comment: Here's a wikipedia entry that seems to suggest that affine subspaces and flats can be used interchangeably: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space#Affine_subspaces_and_parallelism

Comment: Just to make a stupid comment: [A module can also be flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module), although vector spaces always have this property so somebody doing functional analysis is unlikely to think flat to mean this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that "Euclidian space" and "linear space" is somewhat different in definition which means that you can't just move the definition from one to another.

While we of course could define the corresponding subset in terms of linear space the choice of term might not be the best. The generally accepted term would be affine subspace (affine means that it's like a subspace except it doesn't have to pass the origin).

Two things to note is that the construct does not rely on there being a metric at all on the space. Also an affine subspace does not need to be a linear space (in this regard it differs from the Euclidian space counterpart which is an Euclidian space in it's own right).

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a Banach space. $X$ is said to be flat, if there is a function $f:[0,2] \to X$ such that

$||f(t)||=1$ for all $t \in [0,2]$,

$f(0)=-f(2)$

and

$||f(t)-f(s)|| \le |t-s|$ for all $t,s \in [0,2]$.

Comment: I've never heard of this usage of the term "flat". It seems to have little to do with the usage I want, but I guess it's a good argument to look for a different term.

Comment: I'm just curious, is there a reason they are using $[0,2]$ instead of $[0,1]$? It seems like it is nothing a re-parametrization wouldn't fix with appropriate constants in the last condition, of course.

Comment: @Ravi Well, it looks like it is necessary, because the distance between $f(0)$ and $f(2)$ is going to be $2$, so I don't think there will be a non-expansive mapping from a length $1$ interval between them.